# PostgreSQL - How to select every second line of a group function?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join

Let's suppose I have two tables, posts and users, what I want is to select every second post of every user (each post has it's date, so I can order it).

I already read about offset and limit, but none of them has solved my problem (at least no the way I tried). I do think what I'm looking for is some kind of group function because it needs to work in every single group (1 user - N posts) and not only in the final output.

I'm using an inner join to select the combined data.

Can anybody help me, please?

Table

```
user_id   post_id       date         post_name
  1          1       2018-01-01       post 1
  1          2       2018-02-02       post 2
  1          3       2018-03-03       post 3
  2          4       2018-01-01       post 1
  2          5       2018-02-02       post 2
  2          6       2018-03-03       post 3
  3          7       2018-01-01       post 1
  3          8       2018-02-02       post 2
  3          9       2018-03-03       post 3
  4          10      2018-03-03       post 1
```

Expected result

```
user_id   post_id       date         post_name
   1          2       2018-02-02       post 2
   2          5       2018-02-02       post 2
   3          8       2018-02-02       post 2
   4         null        null           null
```

**When the user doesn't have a second post, the value "null" must be set.

Comment: What query are you using?

Comment: I was trying something like this: 

SELECT u.id "user id", u.name, u.email, p.id "post id", p.date, COUNT(*) FROM sql_test.post p
INNER JOIN sql_test.user u ON u.id = p.user_id
WHERE u.id = 1
GROUP BY (u.id, u.name, u.email, p.id, p.date)
ORDER BY p.date
OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `row_number` and `sub-query`

```
select * from
(
select *,row_number() over(partition by user_id   order by date) as rn from tablea
) as t
where rn =2
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3636a/2

According output i changed my query

```
select * from
(
select *,row_number() over(partition by user_id   order by date) as rn from t
) as t
where rn =2
union
select t1.*,null,null,null,null from
(select user_id from t group by user_id having count(*)=1 ) as t1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ee032/6

Comment: Can you help me with one more thing? How do I display "null" for those user who doesnt have a second post? Is it possible?

Comment: @G.R. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b5210/1 You are welcome.  Please don't double post.  And accept this answer  if it worked for you (click the checkbox)...

Comment: @G.R. i changed my answer please check

Comment: @G.R. No need double post

Comment: @G.R. if it helps then please accept answer as  a SO appreciation

Comment: Ok! Done! Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You would use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by user_id order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum % 2 = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.user_id,
(SELECT Users.post_id FROM Users WHERE Users.user_id = A.user_id AND Users.post_name = 'post 2') post_id,
(SELECT Users.date FROM Users WHERE Users.user_id = A.user_id AND Users.post_name = 'post 2') date,
(SELECT Users.post_name FROM Users WHERE Users.user_id = A.user_id AND Users.post_name = 'post 2') post_name
FROM Users AS A
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cc0b4/17

or you can use

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
WHERE post_name = 'post 2'
UNION
SELECT user_id, null, null, null
FROM Users
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) < 2
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cc0b4/21